# Active Directory: Duplicate group membership found

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory, ldap

I am building a process to extract all objects of schema class type contact, computer, user, and group into SQL Server. As part of that process, I am retrieving all group members and inputting that information into a separate table, which has a primary key on the date, memberObjectGuid, and groupObjectGuid. Therefore, I expect a group to only have one instance of a given user. However, I received a primary key violation while loading the data, which shows two instances of the same memberObjectGuid trying to be loaded into the same groupObjectGuid.

Is this allowed? If not, what can cause it (how do I diagnose it) and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group cannot have a duplicate direct member. However, are you including nested groups? An account can be a member of two groups, which are both a member of another group.

For example,

```
     Group A
    /       \
 Group B    Group C
  /             \
User 1       User 1
```

Comment: This is a case of where Group A has two entries of User 1. It is not a nested group issue. I have confirmed this in ADUC. If what you are saying is correct, then any ideas how to diagnose why a group is showing a duplicate?

Comment: So in ADUC, it shows a user twice in the membership list of the same group? I've never seen that.

Comment: Correct. I reached out to our IT Ops group and got push back. I guess they were afraid that it would unravel the fabric of space time. But, I insisted and they corrected it and we are all still here for Friday! Though, I am still curious as to how something like that could happen in the first place. If you, or future readers of this thread know why, or have any useful feedback, I would be grateful for your insights!